# Doctrine Repository Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm doing a project on symfony 6 and I have some problems with my request!
I have a menu + subcategory with products.
The products are only listed in the subcategories
So, I created this request with my repository

```
/**
 * I need 5 articles with the same category
 * @return Articles[] Returns an array of Articles objects
 */
public function FindTheLastFiveArticleWithCategory(): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

and my controller

```
$GroupeCategory = [];
$ArticlesCategory = $this->articlesRepository->FindTheLastFiveArticleWithCategory();
 
foreach ($ArticlesCategory as $cat) {
    $id = $cat->getCatagory()[0]->getId();
    if (isset($GroupeCategory[$id])) {
        $GroupeCategory[$id]['articles'][] = $cat;
    } else {
        $GroupeCategory[$id] = [
            'id'            => $id,
            'category'      => $cat->getCatagory()[0]->getName(),
            'slugCategory'  => $cat->getCatagory()[0]->getSlug(),
            'articles'      => [
                $cat
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Until then, everything works.

BUT
The final result should have been

I want 5 articles / main category

of the type

SELECT all my items from the TABLE items

WHERE

SELECT all my items from the table item WHERE product name = short sleeve shirt limit 5

SELECT all my items from the table item WHERE product name = jeans *** limit 5

SELECT all my items from the table item WHERE product name = watch *** limit 5

Comment: I just test before post. I'm update my post

Comment: your repository-method is named `...WithCategory` but the querybuilder is not containing any statement "with category" ?

Comment: Euh!!! I understand, but I don't know where to start! yes, I put a WHERE with a LIMIT, it only works on one category, but not on all that I have!

Answer (score 0):

I try with another code but also not work

```
        $FindCategory    = $this->categoryRepository->findBy(['SubCategory' => NULL]);
        $FindSubCategory = [];

        foreach ($FindCategory as $key => $find) {
            $CategoryId        = $find->getId(); // J'ai bien les ID des catégorie principale 1 , 6 , 11 , 16, 19
            
            // Je vais chercher les informtion des sous-catégorie principale
            $FindSubCategory[$key] = $this->categoryRepository->findBy(['SubCategory' => $CategoryId]);  

            // Je vérifie que l'ID de la sous catégorie est = a l'id de la catégorie principale
            if ( $CategoryId == $FindCategory[$key]->getId() ) {
                 
                // Je vais envoyer dans le tableau les informations des articles lier a la sous catégorie
                $FindSubCategory[$key] = [
                    'id'          => $find->getId(), // J'ai besoin de l'ID catégorie principale
                    'nom'         => $find->getName(), // J'ai besoin du nom de la catégorie principale
                    'slug'        => $find->getSlug(), // J'ai besoin du slug de la catégorie principale
                    'articles' => [
                        $find->getArticles() // Les articles qui sont lier au sous catégorie
                    ]
                ];

            } else {

            }
        }

        dump($FindSubCategory);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query on your Repository.

This permits you to get last 5 products for each category ordered by date.

Of course up to you to customize your research.

My test stack is Sylfony 6.1, php8.1 and Ubuntu 22.04

```
/**
 * Get last 5 Items for each category
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function GetLastFiveForEachCategory(): array
{

    $query = "SELECT x.category_name, x.product_name
        FROM (
                SELECT p1.product_name, category_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p1.category_id ORDER BY p1.createdAt DESC) AS n
                FROM products p1 
                LEFT JOIN categories c1 ON c1.id = p1.category_id
                ) AS x
        WHERE n <= 5";

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('category_name', 'category_name');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('product_name', 'product_name');

    return $this->em->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm)->getResult();

}
```